# jQuery Validation Phone Number Prefix

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm new to jQuery validation method, I wish to make it to check the the prefix. I tried doing it but it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

Conditions:-

- Must be starting 158 or 131 or 189

Example: 
158XXXXXXXX，131XXXXXXXX，189XXXXXXXX

- Must be equal to 11 characters
- Only numbers, no alphabets or other characters

This is what I have done:

```
$.validator.addMethod("mobile_phone", function (value, element) {
    value = value.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || /^158\d{8}$/.test(value);
});

fr_contact_number: {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    mobile_phone: true,
    minlength: 11,
    maxlength: 11,
}
```

Comment: `value = value.replace(/\s+/g, "");`, I'd suggest to use `\D+` which will remove all non-digit characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex

```
^1(58|31|89)[0-9]{8}$
```

**Explanation:**

1. `^`: Start of line
2. `1`: Matches 1 literally
3. `(58|31|89)`: OR condition, matches any one from the conditions
4. `[0-9]{8}`: Matches any digit from 0 to 9, eight times
5. `$`: End of line

**Regex Demo:**

```css
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input pattern="1(58|31|89)[0-9]{8}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex

```
^1(?:58|31|89)\d{8}$
```

This is explicitly restricting the second and third place to combinations 58, 31, 89 as stated in your requirements. The accepted answer allows to combine the second and third place freely, e.g. allowing 159 as starting numbers.